# How to use unicodes effectively on cross-platform sites?

Tags: fonts, design, unicode

I was trying to use the 'ELECTRIC LIGHT BULB (U+1F4A1)' unicode on my site. Every platform shows the unicode different, even though I specify Symbola font on the font-family on the body tag (all characters use this font except for unicodes).

Linux: Symbola font
Windows: Segio UI font
Android: emoji

Now this might not look like a problem because every platform shows the right icon. It is a problem when you try to change the color, which is something I expect from a character, does not work with emoji.

Also the characters showing different on every platform in general is kind of annoying.

How can I use unicodes effectively, avoiding differences across platforms?

Comment: It's not "a unicode", it's "a Unicode character". The Unicode character U+1F4A1 is in Unicode since October 2010, according to [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a1/index.htm), so you can't expect it to be widely supported.

Comment: @WalterTross when I link to Symbola font, which supports U+1F4A1, inside a project, I expect all platforms to make use of this font and not use Segio UI (which does have the character) on Windows or emojis on Android.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using `@font-face` to download the Symbola font to the client?

Comment: @w3d Yes, the font is locally available inside the project. All characters work except for the unicodes.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make an unicode icon display across browsers consistently is by loading the icon's default webfont. For example, the electric light bulb unicode character uses the [Symbola font](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a1/fontsupport.htm). If that isn't installed on the device, the device will then use the fall-back of the fonts you listed.

For a cross-platform solution, you'll need to use font icons like [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). It's also pretty easy to create your own font icons with [Icomoon](http://icomoon.io). That or you'll need to load each icons webfont which isn't at all practical.